# reading specific bytes from a file in client server program

Tags: java, client-server

I'm new in Java. I'll take the risky job of asking you a very simple question.

I have been given in an assignment wherein I need to make a client-server program in Java. The client should read some specified numbers of characters from a file and send it to server. The server will sort the data and will send it back to client.
The problem is I dont know which API to use for reading the characters.

Comment: can you explain exactly what you're having trouble with?

Comment: hope, this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578476/client-server-application-java

Comment: I have made the question clearer now. PLz reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is called `java.io` and `java.net`. They are default in Java. So import the packages:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
```

Then for reading specific bytes, use [`RandomAccessFile`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) at the client-side. Use the [`seek(long)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) method to go to a specific place in a file. Then you can read the data using the default read methods.

To send data to the server and vise versa, use [`Socket`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html). If you don't know anything about working with sockets, use google and search for `java socket`. Surely check the "Related questions" you can find int the right of this page.

I answered on this question with a very long answer:
[make a client server java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615958/make-a-client-server-java-application)